# Assigning text to UILabel gives error after parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uilabel

I've the following code for receiving response from PHP web service in JSON Format:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
    [self getData:responseStringWithEncoded];
}

-(void) getData:(NSString *) responseStringWithEncoded{
    NSData *data = [responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"object for key ime = %@", [json objectForKey:@"imei"]);
    NSString * jimei = [json objectForKey:@"imei"];
    NSLog(@"jimei = %@", jimei);

    //  NSDictionary * jimei = [json objectForKey:@"imei"];
   imeiLable.text = jimei;
}
```

I am successfully retrieving data in simulator but when assigning one value among received string(NSDictionary) to `imeiLable.text` it gives following error.

Here is the output:

> Request data  =  { URL: http://localhost/getjsonimei.php?imei=478593219801234 }
>
> Response from Server : {"id":7,"imei":478593219801234,"mname":"Samsung Glaxy","pamount":"2000 rupees","pname":"Faizi","address":"House number 88, block 31","cnumber":11122233,"nic":"87456893"}
>
> object for key ime = 478593219801234
>
> jimei = 478593219801234

Here is detailed description of simulator resulting string(dictionary) and error.

```
2017-05-24 20:01:13.229 imiechecker[4005:61372] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb01b3472adbb0923
2017-05-24 20:01:13.263 imiechecker[4005:61372] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb01b3472adbb0923'
```

I also tried following approach:

```
NSDictionary * jimei = [json objectForKey:@"imei"];
```

but having the same error.

Please suggest where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: `[json objectForKey:@"imei"]` is a `NSNumber`, not a `NSString`. So in order to work: `NSString * jimei = [[json objectForKey:@"imei"] stringValue];`

Comment: Good, It works, Pretty Cool... Thanks @Lame

Comment: @Maddy, I don't know why you made so many changes in my question, you mistyped many things in order to get some reputation, which makes no sense in programing, just like `    self getData:responseStringWithEncoded];
` this line was earlier written as `    [self getData:responseStringWithEncoded];
` whereas over all programing concept goes wrong with your moderation, 
Actually I am new to the site and quite unknown about its pure rules & regulations otherwise i also used to report your editing skills. SO please remove your editing by yourself. coz I've got a good answer before your editing.

Comment: Actually, I think rmaddy's edit was, for the most part, a great improvement on the question's formatting. Sure, he introduced one tiny little error, but it's a lot easier to read than what you had. I inserted the `[` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your IMEI number is of data type `NSNumber`, not `NSString`.

Try this:

```
  NSString * jimei = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"imei"]];

    imeiLable.text = jimei;
```